# Ajax Action Link Styling

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having trouble styling my AjaxAction Links to meet design spec.

the html link looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="button"><span class="icon-search"></span>&nbsp;Search</a>
```

Notice the span in within the link, this is using a web font to create icons.

My action link at this point looks like:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Search", "results", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "placeholder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { @class = "button", })
```

I'm new to C# / ASP.Net / MVC , and am stuck as to how I can achieve this.

Does anybody know if their is a way to do this?

Comment: I see a class on your link and on your span.  What is the issue you are having?  Can't you just use those classes as selectors in the css and style how you want?

Comment: Im'm not able to include the span within the action link.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Extension method for customize @Ajax.ActionLink.
   For example: ImageAjaxLink

```
 public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string imageUrl, string titleText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
        builder.MergeAttribute("title", titleText);
        var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, controllerName, routeValues, ajaxOptions, htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(link.Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
    }
```

apply the so-

```
 @Ajax.ImageActionLink("image.png","Link",...)
```